# Could missing field error be causing the authentication to fail? It is being processed through the logs on commerce.js

Tags: commerce

{
"status_code": 422,
"error": {
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"type": "unprocessable_entity",
"errors": {
"extrafields.extr_ANwRdrnkGbz5vY": [
"The Shipping address field is required."
]
}
},

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `Shipping address` when posting your data